# Duration of rotating and sliding down an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

A cylinder and a square cube, both with the same mass, are placed on top of an incline with friction and then let go. The cylinder rolls down without sliding, while the cube slides. They arrive at the bottom at the same time, is this correct? And it could be derived from the formula $$\frac{1}{2}(g\sin\theta-g\mu \cos\theta )t^2=x$$ with $x$ being the incline length, $\theta$ the slope angle, $\mu$ the friction constant?

Comment: Would you please write the expression with proper mathematical formatting.

Comment: Showing your derivation would also be helpful.

Comment: It's the $1/2at^2$ formula, assuming the acceleration stays constant throughout motion. The net force acting on it is its weight minus the friction force, $mgsinθ−mgμcosθ$, dividing by the mass should give the net translational acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time taken by the cylinder and the cube will not be same, as in this particular case they have different accelarations.

Since the cylinder is rolling its accelaration of center of mass will not be the one you gave in your equation. The fact that its rolling on the incline plane, will lead to a different acceleration, and i am letting you figure out what it is.
(Just as a hint i am adding a picture) [image]

On the other hand, the time you found out through your equation is the time taken for cube to come down the incline, since its slipping.

Comment: Why would their translational accelerations be different? The net force acting on them is the same.

Comment: But you have to take rolling in consideration

Comment: Now since rolling is taking place, friction never reaches its maximum value of (μN), snd hence your equation is wrong for cylinder

Comment: Now that I look at it again, the friction acting on the cylinder should be $mgsinθ/3$, but how would I prove that it'd be smaller than the $μmgcosθ$ acting on the cube?

Comment: It has to be so, its like a condition for rolling, if it is stated that rolling occurs, it must be less or at the maximum to that value of limiting friction

Comment: Then, cylinders rolling down inclines with angles greater than $arctan(3μ)$ or friction coefficient lesser than $(1/3)tanθ$ will also slide while rolling. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes that would be correct, it will roll without slipping